# SWT FileDialog in Applet does not show up

Tags: java, swing, swt

I am not a SWT user, but I need one of its functionality in JApplet I am working on: FileDialog. And I have problem when I run applet withing a browser: the dialog will not popup, no exception is thrown, nothing (but blink of the window) happens.

Applet is only for Windows users, that is the requirement.

When I run the same applet from appletviewer in Eclipse, it works fine.

I added all the SWT libraries to the PATH in Windows, so they should be available for VM. I searched over the Internet, but I could not find anything that could help me.

The code I am using:

```
final Display display = new Display();
    final java.awt.Canvas awtParent = new java.awt.Canvas();

    applet.getApplet().add(awtParent);

    final Shell swtParent = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(display, awtParent);
    try {
        FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(swtParent, SWT.OPEN);
        dialog.setFilterExtensions(getMediaFilesExtensions());
        dialog.setFilterNames(new String[] {"All files", "Media Files"});
        String fileName = dialog.open();
        File[] files = null;
        if (fileName != null) {
            files = new File[] { new File(dialog.getFileName()) };
        }
        return files;
    } finally {         
        display.syncExec(new Runnable () {
            public void run () {
                if (swtParent != null && !swtParent.isDisposed ()) swtParent.dispose ();                    
                display.dispose ();
                applet.getApplet().remove(awtParent);
            }
        });
    }
```

This code is called while user click on the button. The rest of the application is Swing based.

I work on Windows 7 with SWT 3.7.1. All the DLLs are in java.library.path (%PATH% in windows)

Do you have any advice?

BTW: Swing with native L&F is not an option. I need native file selection dialog.

This is the runnable demo applet I created. It requires: swt-win32-x86-3.7.jar.

```
package com.applet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class DemoApplet extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Select files") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File[] filesNative = getFilesNative();
                String msg = "Selected files: " + Arrays.toString(filesNative);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(mainPanel);
        super.init();
    }

    private File[] getFilesNative() {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final java.awt.Canvas awtParent = new java.awt.Canvas();

        add(awtParent);

        final Shell swtParent = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(display, awtParent);
        try {
            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(swtParent, SWT.OPEN);
            dialog.setFilterNames(new String[] {"All files", "Media Files"});
            String fileName = dialog.open();
            File[] files = null;
            if (fileName != null) {
                files = new File[] { new File(dialog.getFileName()) };
            }
            return files;
        } finally {         
            display.syncExec(new Runnable () {
                public void run () {
                    if (swtParent != null && !swtParent.isDisposed ()) swtParent.dispose ();                    
                    display.dispose ();
                    remove(awtParent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide runnable Applet example with the button which reacts with dialog opening?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/jws/controlexample.jnlp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dialog in an applet you must find the parent frame.  I ran into this issue recently as well and found this useful: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=27423

```
public Frame findParentFrame(){
    java.awt.Component c = getParent();

    while(true) {
        if(c instanceof Frame)
            return (Frame)c;
        c = c.getParent();
    }
}
```

This will get you the parent frame, which you pass to the dialog constructor:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(findParentFrame(), "Save Building", FileDialog.SAVE);
```

Note that some browsers might block this as a popup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java SE 6u26, you might be running into [Bug 7056092](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7056092) - updating to [Java SE 6u27](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u27-download-440405.html) fixed the issue of file dialogs not opening in SWT apps for me

Answer (score 0):

"no exception is thrown, nothing (but blink of the window) happens"
SWT usually write logfiles instead of throwing exceptions in case of display problems (in generally). I don't know much about SWT based applets, but i wondered, is there any logfile in this case?

Comment: Nothing appears in Console, no uncaught exception, just nothing. Nothing happens. I expected some dynamic library loading error or security (applet is signed) - nothing happens. And this is rather strange. In non-example code log4j is setup.